# How to install VMware Player?

Tags: installation, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to obtain and install VMware Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136008/how-to-obtain-and-install-vmware-player)

I want to install VMware Player 4.0.2 on my Ubuntu 11.10, but I don't know how.
Can someone help me with a step by step tutorial?