# Is there any version of VMware player for ubuntu available?

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install VMware Player 4.0.2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101139/how-to-install-vmware-player-4-0-2)

Is there any version of VMware player for ubuntu available?

How can I install it, if there is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Virtualbox is available from repositories, it is a very similar program that will do equally well in most situations.

Comment: Yes, I knew that. But I use the `VMware player` in `Windows` and I want to know can I use it in `Ubuntu` too?

Comment: VMware is available. There is an answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/101139/how-to-install-vmware-player-4-0-2

Comment: Fair enough. Not because I want to convince you should use Virtualbox, but it can load VMware images BTW and I believe vice versa too.