# Installing VMware player: "chmod: cannot access... no such file or directory"

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, vmware

I'm trying to download vmware player on my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop and I am using [another website to guide me](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-vmware-player-in-ubuntu.html). I get stuck at entering the `chmod` command in the terminal, it says:

```
hpnerd@hpnerd-CF-52AJCHDBM:~$ chmod +x VMware-Player-4.0.3-703057.i386.bundle
chmod: cannot access `VMware-Player-4.0.3-703057.i386.bundle': No such file or directory
```

I also downloaded a Storage device manager as suggested in an answer to another question that was related to vmware but so far it's not working.

Comment: Why don't you get the current player version from vmware, 4.03 is pretty old.  If the file is in your current directory, the chmnod should work (if the name is correct).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install VMware Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136008/how-do-i-install-vmware-player) (The `.bundle` filename contains a version number, so its specific name won't usually be the same as whatever name is given in any particular guide.)

Answer (score 0):

To install VMware Player 6, you need first to do some prerequisites.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Then go ahead and download [VMware Player 6](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0%7CPLAYER-600-A%7Cproduct_downloads), the file will download to your Downloads folder.  Once the download is done, navigate to the Downloads folder, and:

```
cd Downloads
chmod +x VMware-Player*
sudo ./VMware-Player-6.0.0*
```

During the installation when asked for a license number, skip that unless you got a key for player plus which is a paid product.<sup>[VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/)</sup>