# E: Unable to locate package VMware-Player-15.0.2-10952284.x86_64.bundle

Tags: software-installation, vmware-player

I'm trying to install VMWare Player. I've downloaded .bundle file in ***~/Downloads***. To install I switched to root account, changed directory to ***~/Downloads*** and ran `apt-get install VMware-Player-15.0.2-10952284.x86_64.bundle`. But I'm getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package VMware-Player-15.0.2-10952284.x86_64.bundle
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'VMware-Player-15.0.2-10952284.x86_64.bundle'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'VMware-Player-15.0.2-10952284.x86_64.bundle'
```

How do I install VMWare successfully?

Comment: Please copy paste the texts in those images!

Comment: @Kulfy I'm not sure this qualifies since OP in *that* question is asking how to I install and then custom-patch it with a custom script they have.

Comment: @Kulfy I agree with that assessment but most users won't see it because they never read past the original accepted answer on dupe posts.  (Hopefully my bounty will raise awareness to the proper other answer when I can award it)

Comment: @ThomasWard Now since the posts have been un-merged, should it be considered as dupe of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/136008/816190)?

Comment: @Kulfy yes, i would think so.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

That VMware bundle can't be installed with `apt-get`.  It's its own standalone installer package.

Run `chmod +x` on the bundle, then execute it with `sudo ./VMware-Player-*.bundle`

This is the only way to run the VMware installer, as it is **NOT** an `apt` compatible package, but its own installation package that runs itself on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give installer permission to execute and run it.

```
chmod +x Vmware-Player-15.0.2-10952284.x86_64.bundle
```

Now you would be run it.

```
./Vmware-Player-15.0.2-10952284.x86_64.bundle
```

Comment: That only works on Debian packages, not VMware's `.bundle` installers as they are not Debian packages.