# How do I install VMWare Workstation on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 19.04, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to create a virtual machine to follow a course and I don't have much practice in Ubuntu.
The machine in this case is VMWare Workstation and I don't know exactly how to do it.

I have seen several questions about this on this site, but they are old and from very earlier versions of Ubuntu.
Is there any new way to install this machine on my PC?

Comment: Have you downloaded executable bundle file from their website? Have tried running that using `chmod +x filename; ./filename`? Did you get any error?

Comment: Thanks @Kulfy,  I still did nothing, as I say so far install all the programs you need from the Ubuntu store, but there is no Vmware Workstation, so I do not know how to proceed. What is the best option that you advise me?

Comment: Workstation pro is paid while Workstation player is free. There ain't any special instruction for 19.04. You can download it from [here](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/downloads) and follow instructions from [Eliah's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/136115/816190) or [Vinoth's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181837/816190)

Comment: Thanks for support @Kulfy, I have visited the question you suggest, but the download link is broken. Is there another site where I can download?

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated. Consider following Eliah's answer or the link I attached in comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install VMware Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136008/how-do-i-install-vmware-player) (the same technique, including download instructions for the `.bundle` file, applies to VMware Workstation as well)